# Free commercial maps with SSL support

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ssl, maps

The commercial web app I am developing resides inside an SSL environment. I have been using Yahoo Maps up until now when I realised that when I switch to my secure SSL environment YMaps breaks the SSL certificate. I know Google Maps now offer SSL support but do not allow for commercial use unless you upgrade to Premier for a mere $10,000 dollars a year! This is out of the question for my tiny start-up.

**Basically I need a free mapping service that will deliver all content from an https domain. Does this exist?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using [leafletJS](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com) maps which allows you to specify the URL of your map tiles. I passed the tile image file contents through a very simple PHP proxy page on my server. That way the SSL is not broken by the client-side requesting resources from an unsecure http domain.

**Word of warning on [PolyMaps](http://polymaps.org):** IE<9 does not run them as they require SVG support. Found this out the hard way!

If anyone wants more info on how I solved my problem just comment back.

Answer (score 1):

Even if it does exist, a couple considerations:

1) You get what you pay for: will the 'free ssl maps' be the same quality as google/yahoo maps? Will they even be close?

2) Unless its a treasure map, why do they need to be served under ssl? They don't have any user-specific information in them (assuming you use client-side javascript to tag/mashup)

3) As for the cert issue, look into protocol neutral urls, granted you will have to suck it up and not mind having a pop up in IE 6

Comment: 1. http://Polymaps.org is a good example of a high quality alternative
2. The maps are located on a page that does hold other secure information. I therefore don't want to worry users when they see the https break.
3. I googled 'Protocol Neutral URLs' and found nothing, any more info on this?